# How to record audio on button press hold and play the recorded audio on button release

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner in unity development.I'm trying to do an android app in unity where the user can record audio press holds a button and when he releases it, the recorded audio must play on the loop.
Until now I learned how o record audio from the microphone, and also the play function to play back the audio.

Things that I am unable to do

1.Cannot use button press hold and release function
2.Cannot locate the saved recording in my project directory.

I have followed [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/354401/save-audio-to-a-file.html) to record and playback audio
And I have implemented the same block of code.
What it's doing right now is recording my voice and playing it back as I record, on button click.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

This is the code implementation i have tried:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class audiorecorder : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioClip reco;
    // Use this for initialization
    public void onClick() {
    AudioSource aud;
        aud = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        foreach(string device in Microphone.devices)
        {
            Debug.Log(device);
        }
    reco = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 10, 44100);
    aud.clip = reco;

    aud.Play();
}

}
```

Comment: You need to show what you have done, your code implementation. So that it will be easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with a mouse up and down you have to use the `IPointDownHandler` and the `IPointerUpHandler` interfaces that are in the `UnityEngine.EventSystems` namespace. To use your systems default microphone you should give the `Microphone.Start` function an empty string for the device name

The script below should work, but I didn't get a chance to test it because I have no microphone right now.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

//Use the PointerDown and PointerUP interfaces to detect a mouse down and up on a ui element
public class AudioRecorder : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler{
    AudioClip recording;
    //Keep this one as a global variable (outside the functions) too and use GetComponent during start to save resources
    AudioSource audioSource;
    private float startRecordingTime;

    //Get the audiosource here to save resources
    private void Start()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //End the recording when the mouse comes back up, then play it
        Microphone.End("");

        //Trim the audioclip by the length of the recording
        AudioClip recordingNew = AudioClip.Create(recording.name, (int)((Time.time - startRecordingTime) * recording.frequency), recording.channels, recording.frequency, false);
        float[] data = new float[(int)((Time.time - startRecordingTime) * recording.frequency)];
        recording.GetData(data, 0);
        recordingNew.SetData(data, 0);
        this.recording = recordingNew;

        //Play recording
        audioSource.clip = recording;
        audioSource.Play();

    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Get the max frequency of a microphone, if it's less than 44100 record at the max frequency, else record at 44100
        int minFreq;
        int maxFreq;
        int freq = 44100;
        Microphone.GetDeviceCaps("", out minFreq, out maxFreq);
        if (maxFreq < 44100)
            freq = maxFreq;

        //Start the recording, the length of 300 gives it a cap of 5 minutes
        recording = Microphone.Start("", false, 300, 44100);
        startRecordingTime = Time.time;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Steffan, thanks a lot for the quick response. Currently what i want is instead of a mouse click, i want to do this with a GUI button. The android application that i'm working on should have the functionality of recording audio when the ui button is pressed and held down, and when the button is released it should be able to play back the audio recorded on loop.

Comment: Using the point down and up handler that should work, they only trigger when the pointer (or touch) goes down on the UI element you add this script to. If you have your audiosource set to loop it will loop the recorded audio

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It's working. I'll mail you the app if you want to see it.

Answer (score 1):

SavWav: (you'll need to add it as a script in your project) [code](https://gist.github.com/darktable/2317063)

`using System.Threading;` (for sleep function)

```
int frequency = 44100; //Wav format frequency
int numberOfSecondsToRecord = 10;

var rec = Microphone.Start("", false, numberOfSecondsToRecord, frequency);
Thread.Sleep(numberOfSecondsToRecord * 1000); //To miliseconds
if(rec != null)
{
  SavWav.Save(Application.persistentDataPath + "/test.wav", rec);
}
```

What the above code basically does is it starts the microphone which, if done successfully, returns the audioclip of the live audio being recorded, you must then wait until the recording finishes and only then save it.